# Read, from standard input, a person’s family name, their first name and their home location – each on a separate line

Tags: java

hi im a total beginner and lost in class when we do java this is the code i have but it will not read persons name lastname and location

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String firstName,lastName,location;


        //Create scanner to obtain user input
         Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner( System.in );

        //obtain user input
         System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");
         firstName = scanner1.nextLine();

         System.out.println("Enter your last name: ");
         lastName = scanner1.nextLine();

         System.out.println("Enter your location: ");
         lastName = scanner1.nextLine();

        //output information
         System.out.print("Hello + firstName + " + "lastName + "location )
    }
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile. The ``System.out.print`` statement has a syntax error. Is that your question?

Comment: I dont think this will even compile as your last `sysout` has error

Comment: sorry im just trying to get it to work i had it going before but messed up somehow but it just read hello firtname lastname location instead of the names i typed in

Answer (score 0):

It does with slight modification, For location you are assigning again back to lastName

```
System.out.println("Enter your location: ");
lastName = scanner1.nextLine();
```

After slight modification we can see the below console output

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String firstName,lastName,location;


        //Create scanner to obtain user input
         Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner( System.in );

        //obtain user input
         System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");
         firstName = scanner1.nextLine();

         System.out.println("Enter your last name: ");
         lastName = scanner1.nextLine();

         System.out.println("Enter your location: ");
         location = scanner1.nextLine();

         System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName + " " + location);

    }
```

Console output

```
Enter your first name: 
Fairoz
Enter your last name: 
Matte
Enter your location: 
Bangalore
Fairoz Matte Bangalore
```

Comment: how would you make it say hello fairoz matte from bangalore?

Comment: Run the program in the consol enter the details.